# LightSwitch project failed to load after merging Git branches

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I've a LightSwitch project under Git source control.
I merged two branches and got conflicts, after solving them my project wont load and gives me this error:

> Error 1   Item with id 'LightSwitchApplication.RentEx.DesktopClient:'
>   conflicts with another model item in file
>   'F:\Projects\RentEx\RentEx\RentEx.DesktopClient\Properties\Proxies.lsml'. F:\Projects\RentEx\RentEx\RentEx.DesktopClient\Properties\Proxies.lsml  0   1

This error is repeated five times !

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAW9M.png)

Comment: At least clarify the down grading purpose ?

Comment: Take a copy of the whole project and try manually editing Proxies.lsml and Client.lsml to get them back into sync with each other and the solution itself. Or revert within Git to a good copy assuming that's an option - I don't know Git well enough to say how.

Comment: I'll redo the merge, I maybe missed something. So the problem is that proxies and client files aren't synced? .. Lightswitch doesn't go will with source control

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this question, it's an extremely important issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem: There were 2+ commits that included a modified DataSource.  I worked on a large LightSwitch project recently with approximately 6 developers.  We were in merge hell like you until we realised what was going on.

To avoid the issue here's what you and every other developer on your team must do:

1. git pull
2. make changes to your database and DataSource
3. git add, commit and push!

If you don't want to check in your current branch, just commit your work to a new branch first, then switch to the main branch, update the DataSource and push.  This way your Proxies.lsml doesn't 'break'.

Alternatively you could do the whole lsml ninja thing and manually go through the changes in the Proxies.lsml every time, in my experience this can take up to a few hours to fix.

Good luck.

Comment: This looks good, I will keep it in mind. but it seems to be my last project on lightswitch, I'm having nightmares. Thanks